# Javascript [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, php, object

```
<body onload="check(<?php echo($type);?>,<?php echo($bool);?>)">
    #code...
</body>

function check(var1,var2)
{
   alert(var1);
   if (var2 == true)
   {
      edit(var1);   
   };
}
# var1 is a string
# var2 is a true/false boolean

# var2 works just fine, passes through the FALSE/TRUE value without problems
# var1 on the other hand is the problem.
```

Hello everyone, i'm trying to pass PHP a variable into my javascript function.
the variable $type isset to "email", like this;

```
$data['type'] = "email";
```

But for some reason the javascript function automatically picks the value of my email input instead of the value that i assigned to the $type variable.

If i set $type to something else, like this;

```
$data['type'] = "random";
```

Note: I've been trying to alert(); the value just to make sure it's the correct value.

So if i try to alert(type); from within the javascript function and 'type' is set to anything that DOESN'T exist in my form, nothing happens.

If i set 'type' do something that DOES exist in my form(e.g. password, email) it will automatically alert(); the value from my form inputs, and not the value i assigned to $data['type'] in my PHP function.

Anyone got a clue what the problem is?

Comment: Quote-escape it and put it in a JavaScript string literal if that is what it is supposed to become?

Comment: Never compare a boolean against `true`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding quotes around var1
Like this :

```
<body onload="check('<?php echo($type);?>',<?php echo($bool);?>)">
```

Comment: But make sure to escape apostrophes and backslashes (for JS) and quotes (for HTML)!